# How do I combine intermediate video and audio input in filter_complex using shortest input?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have one video and one audio stream (for simplicity) and try to combine them (so that the result ends where the shortest input ends). This definition works but the resulting output is as long as the longest of inputs. I need the shortest.

```
[video][audio:a]concat=n=1:v=1:a=1[out];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `shortest` option (information [there](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#toc-Advanced-options)).
You could use such command:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i input.mp3 -shortest output.mp4
```

Comment: Yes, I need to do this in "filter_complex" parameter for an intermediate inputs, though.

Comment: If you have one audio and one video and you want them played at the same time you shouldn't use `concat` which is for adding a stream after another.

Comment: The example I provided works as it uses 1 video and 1 audio input (which are considered one input with two streams by concat). What should I use then?

Comment: If you use `concat`, the streams on input will be put one after the other on the output. So there will only be one bigger stream exiting the filter. If you just want to put a video and an audio together, just use my example above without filter. If you want to concatenate multiple videos and audios then your question makes no sense to me.

Comment: I need to add audio to video clip in filter_complex but the result need to have the length of the video (the audio is longer)

Comment: As I said before, you don't need `complex_filter` for that. just use this command: `ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i input.mp3 -shortest output.mp4`